# Accessing the structure of a dll in dotnet reg

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Is it possible to know the total structure of a dll as

1. names of variables used
2. signature used
3. declarations used
4. variables used
5. class used
6. method used

with code or without code through c#.net code without using any decompiler.

is it possible to scan the dll through automation there by listing out

1) what all the packages imported in it
2) class used in it
3) method used in it  etc......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is [System.Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx) namespace

Comment: can you provide me some sample links code to solve my problem?

Comment: check if this helps http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/reflection/article.php/c4257/An-Introduction-to-Reflection-in-C.htm

Answer (score 2):

**Without writing code**

Use software [Reflector software for .net](http://www.reflector.net/?utm_expid=53707066-1&utm_referrer=http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=reflector&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGAQFjAA&url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.reflector.net%252F&ei=OCHYT8I76b3RBb_W8JoE&usg=AFQjCNFUYKHS6YOhMQfDr2BkY_QXx9SZEQ)

**With writing code**

You can use Reflection Namespace provided by .net [**Reflection in Dot Net**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx). You can also you use some software to get member information of assembly.

Comment: can you provide me some sample links code to solve my problem?

Comment: you can also use telerik version that is a new and good one. find it at http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx